# External HDD keeps spinning up

Tags: 20.04, usb, hard-drive, lts

Hello Ubuntu Community!

my Problem is a external USB Housing with two Ports. One equipped with an SSD and the other one with an HDD. The SSD does the daily work, the HDD is for Backups only.
The HDD keeps spinning up very often, i assume every 20 Minutes. But Backups are just 2-3x per Day. I tried "noauto" and systemd-mount for the HDD, but it keeps spinning up.

System is an Rasperry Pi 3B+ running Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 LTS.

Here is the dmesg Detail from the Housing

```
[    6.371979] usb 1-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[    6.473823] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0551, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    6.473834] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[    6.473840] usb 1-1.1.2: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[    6.473846] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: JMicron
[    6.473853] usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 152D20551000
[    6.474947] usb-storage 1-1.1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    6.475387] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.1.2:1.0
[    6.783563] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.745612] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  SSD 840 EVO 500G      PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[    9.746049] scsi 1:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ST2000DM 008-2UB102            PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[    9.746724] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    9.747063] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    9.747136] scsi 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    9.747417] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    9.747426] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[    9.747785] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[    9.748087] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    9.748401] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    9.753576] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    9.753578] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[    9.753877] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[    9.765295] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    9.818826]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[    9.819152]  sdb: sdb1
[    9.833642] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    9.833895] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 152d:0551 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS551 SuperSpeed two ports SATA 3Gb/s bridge
```

lsblk

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /SSD
sdc           8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1        8:33   0     1T  0 part /HD1
└─sdc2        8:34   0   839G  0 part /HD2
```

HDD is shown mounted, most of the Time /HD1 and /HD2 are umounted.

Prior, this Housing was used under Ubuntu 16 with 2 HDD. I think the Issue came up with Ubuntu 20. The change to HDD/SDD came at the same Time.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance
Wolfgang

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 & 20 are different products to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  If you're using 20.04 as mentioned & tagged; please check your system is fully-upgraded as https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ will show the date of ISO release, but installed systems upgraded to it the weekend before that Thursday ISO release date (*at latest*); your details imply an system behind on security patches/fixes.

Comment: Thank you for your  suggestion.Update is done.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1070-raspi armv7l)`